# Is it safe to attach pcapng to question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question i would like to ask, i am novice when it comes to networking, is it safe to add the pcapng to my question?

I feel like i would be inviting unwanted attention to my pci environment, and i do not trust our security.

Thought suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This is a question we cannot answer for you. We don't know what possibly sensitive information is in that PCAP and we don't know which corporate policies you have to follow.

Answer (score 0):

As Teun Vink suggested we are not aware of what could be considered sensitive information (even more if you are novice), hence it will depend on you or whoever calls the final shot.

However if you wish, below are some points that you can think about before posting a pcap file.

- Depending on the question you could try to filter or narrow as much as possible the pcap file to only include the necessary information instead of a long promiscuous file.
- Do you really need to hand over the pcap? Perhaps you could just open it with wireshark and take screenshots of info you want to convey, or that it's ask to you. Perhaps even scratch out addresses or anything you like.
- If you are able to recreate the issue in a lab,  you can share that pcap instead as it won't have 'real' IP or MAC addresses